# Список друзей через Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

Как я могу достать все UID друзей из Firebase и после этого сделать список друзей? Я понимаю как достать конкретные данные, но как достать список, когда там неопределенное количество строк и рандомные названия. Я хочу чтобы код прошелся по всему списку друзей и вытащил UID тех, у которых значение "friend"

JSON:

```
app
   users
        uid
           name
           nickname
           friends
                  friendUid1: friend
                  friendUid2: friend
                  friendUid3: request
```

Я пробовал это:

```
func getFriends() {
   let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
   Database.database().reference().child("users"). child(uid!).child("friends").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Если ты хочешь отобразить список друзей, то нужно копировать часть данных этих друзей(id, imageUrl, имя, и тд) - тогда ты сможешь разом получить список друзей.

В **firesore** это можно реализовать через подколекции: user(collection)->user(document)-> friends(subcollection)->friend(document)

В **realtime-database** подколекций нет. Тогда можно сделать через массив, но все документы имеют ограниченый размер.

Но нужно учитывать, если юзер меняет картинку, то весь твой список устарел, и нужно предпринимать телодвижения для обновления данных у всех юзеров. Или искать способы сэкономить и упростить себе жизнь.

Если хранить только id как у тебя, то нужно делать отдельный запрос для каждого юзера по этому id. Тут другие проблемы - производительность и количество запросов. Если у тебя 500 друзей, то будет сделано 500 запросов, вместо одного - ты платишь, тебе решать.